# Positive predictive value of test only dependent on prevalence and FPR?

Tags: bayesian, validation

I have a question regarding the PPV of a test in the context of the famous conclusion of Bayes test in tests for rare diseases:

The gist is that even highly sensitive and specific tests will make a huge number of false positives, leading to an un-intuitively small positive predictive value/posterior probability of otherwise well-functioning tests. In other words, a positive test result of a good test in a rare disease doesn't mean you're actually likely to have the disease.

I've been trying to wrap my head around the maths a bit more and have read [this blog post](https://www.mateipa.de/posts/2021/04/03/bayes-tests). While I can follow the math, in the end the author shows that the PPV is upper-bound by only the FPR and the prevalence. I find this result extremely hard to intuitively grasp: FPR and prevalence held equal, surely a test that is more sensitive will have a better positive predictive value?

Could someone point out where my thinking is wrong?

Comment: Why should a test that is more sensitive have higher PPV? A test reaches maximum sensitivity by classifying every case as diseased, but the PPV is terrible. I would say that a skeptical (specific) test reporting a case as disease is more likely to have correctly identified a diseases case.

Comment: that's why I said 'FPR and prevalence held equal'. I'm aware that for any given test, sensitivity and specificity are trade-offs, but I'm thinking of a hypothetical scenario here.